Limit $\sigma$-algebra vs. $\sigma$-algebra of limit
Let $\mathcal{Y}$ be a separable (infinite dimensional) Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_i, i = 1, \ldots)$ equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra and let $Y$ be a random variable (defined on some complete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$) taking values in $\mathcal{Y}$. Moreover, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $\pi_n: \mathcal{Y} \rightarrow \text{span} \lbrace e_i, i = 1, \ldots, n \rbrace$ be the orthogonal projector and define the projected family
$$
Y_n := \pi_n \circ Y.
$$
I try to show that
$$
\sigma ( \cup_{i = 1}^\infty \sigma(Y_n)) = \sigma(Y).
$$
Clearly, the lhs is included in $\sigma(Y)$ but I am struggling to show the other inclusion. Do you have a hint/reference for me?
Edit: One can assume that $Y \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{Y})$.

An orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a maximal orthonormal system for $\mathcal{H}$, so for any $u\in \mathcal{H}$ we have $u=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n=\lim_n(\pi_n\circ u)$. Therefore, pointwise $Y(\omega)=\lim_n(\pi_n\circ Y(\omega))=\lim_n Y_n(\omega)$. Since $\lim_n Y_n$ exists pointwise and is $\sigma(\cup_n\sigma(Y_n))$-measurable, we conclude that $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(\lim_nY_n)\subseteq \sigma(\cup_n\sigma(Y_n))$.
